# C Matrix and pointers error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, malloc

This version of this function works good:

```
int** outerProduct(int v[], int n){
    int i, j;
    int **a = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            *(*(a+i)+j) = v[i]*v[j];
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

And this doesn't work:

```
int** outerProduct(int v[], int n){
    int i, j;
    int **a = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            *(a+(i*n)+j) = v[i]*v[j];
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

The error is `*(a+(i*n)+j) = v[i]*v[j];` but I don't understand why. It should be the same thing.

Comment: One dereference versus two? How can it be "the same thing" ? The lhs will even have different types.

Comment: Unlike a 2-D array, there is no guarantee that the rows will be in contiguous memory.

Comment: @WeatherVane aaaah that's right. i didn't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: Something like `int **` is not a matrix (aka 2D array), cannot point to one, nor represent one. If you want a matrix, use one and leave index-calculations to the compiler.

Comment: @Olaf I can't do that, because i don't know the dimension of the matrix. As you can see I have a parameter for that, so I have to allocate a "matrix" dynamically. You're right, it's just a pointer to pointers, but at the end it does the same thing.

Comment: "... I don't know the dimension of the matrix" - A matrix has 2 dimensions! And if you mean _lengths_: What's the problem? Use a VLA, resp. pointer to a VLA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike a 2-D array, there is no guarantee that the rows will be in contiguous memory.

If you make a *single* memory allocation for the whole `n * n` array, then you can index it the way that failed when using an array of pointers to 1-D arrays.